# llamar metodo de codebehind Aspx con Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, aspx

Como puedo colocar un gif de "cargando..." a una pagina aspx al hacer clic en un boton asp:button, sin utilizar webMethods ya que hay elementos html que no lee por ser estatico el metodo

ASPX

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ForeColor="blue"></asp:Label>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h3><span class="label alert-success">Carga Archivos</span></h3>
                        <br />

                        <div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"></div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">
                                    <h4><span class="label label-default">Total</span></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">
                                    <h4><span class="label label-default">Insertados</span></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5">
                                    <h4><span class="label label-default">Archivo</span></h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal" Width="100px" runat="server" Text="0" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProcesado" Width="100px" runat="server" Text="0" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">
                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="fuExcel" runat="server" CssClass="" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnProcesar" runat="server" Text="Procesar" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClick="btnProcesar_Click" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 400px;">

                                <asp:ListBox ID="lstMensaje" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="300px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="Up1" runat="Server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <span style="background-color: #66997A;">
                <img src="img/images.jpg" alt="Please wait" width="100px" />
                Please wait ...</span>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</asp:Content>
```

CODEBEHIND

```html
    protected void btnProcesar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            lblMessage.Text = "Processing completed";
     
                 string Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
            try
            {
                if (fuExcel.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                {

                    String ConnExcel = "";
                    string HojaExcel = "";
                    string pathOriginal = Server.MapPath("Files/" + fuExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
                    if (File.Exists(pathOriginal))
                        File.Delete(pathOriginal);
                    fuExcel.SaveAs(pathOriginal);

                    string nombreArchivo = fuExcel.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();

                    if (fuExcel.PostedFile.FileName.Contains("xlsx"))
                        ConnExcel = "Provider=" + Provider + "; Data Source = " + pathOriginal + "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;READONLY=FALSE\";";
                    else
                        ConnExcel = "Provider=" + Provider + "; Data Source = " + pathOriginal + "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;READONLY=FALSE\";";

                    OleDbConnection ConnLocal = new OleDbConnection(ConnExcel);
                    ConnLocal.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmdLocal = new OleDbCommand("", ConnLocal);
                    System.Data.DataTable dtExcelSheetName = ConnLocal.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    foreach (DataRow drtabla in dtExcelSheetName.Rows)
                        if (drtabla["Table_Name"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("LAYOUT") || drtabla["Table_Name"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("SHEET1") || drtabla["Table_Name"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("TABLE1"))
                        {
                            HojaExcel = drtabla["Table_Name"].ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                    if (HojaExcel == "")
                        HojaExcel = "Hoja1$";

                    OleDbDataAdapter dta = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + HojaExcel + "]", ConnLocal);

                    DataTable dtExcel = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    dta.Fill(dtExcel);


                    Session["Total"] = dtExcel.Rows.Count;
                    

                    int filas = 1;
                    int c = 0;  

                    System.Data.DataTable dtSalida = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("A", typeof(DateTime));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("C", typeof(int));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("D", typeof(int));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("E", typeof(string));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("F", typeof(DateTime));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("G", typeof(int));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("H", typeof(string));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("I", typeof(string)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("J", typeof(float)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("K", typeof(string)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("L", typeof(int)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("M", typeof(int)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("N", typeof(float)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("O", typeof(string)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("P", typeof(int)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("Q", typeof(string)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("R", typeof(DateTime)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("S", typeof(int));
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("T", typeof(float)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("U", typeof(float)).AllowDBNull = true;
                    dtSalida.Columns.Add("V", typeof(string)).AllowDBNull = true;

                    txtTotal.Text = Session["Total"].ToString();

                    float res_dou;
                    int i = 0;

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dtExcel.Rows)
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            DataRow row2 = dtSalida.NewRow();
                            if (float.TryParse(dr["IMPORT_MCMEP"].ToString(), out res_dou) == false)
                            {
                                throw new Exception("Error al formatear");
                            }
                            row2["A"] = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["B"].ToString().Replace("a", "").Replace("m", "").Replace("p", "").Replace(".", "")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                            row2["B"] = dr["B"].ToString().Replace(":", "");
                            row2["C"] = dr["C"].ToString();
                            row2["D"] = dr["D"].ToString();
                            row2["E"] = dr["E"].ToString();
                            row2["F"] = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["F"].ToString().Replace("a", "").Replace("m", "").Replace("p", "").Replace(".", "")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                            row2["G"] = dr["G"].ToString();
                            row2["H"] = dr["H"].ToString();
                            row2["I"] = dr["I"].ToString();
                            row2["J"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["K"] = dr["K"].ToString();
                            row2["L"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["M"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["N"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["O"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["P"] = Convert.ToInt32(dr["P"]);
                            row2["Q"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["R"] = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["R"].ToString().Replace("a", "").Replace("m", "").Replace("p", "").Replace(".", "")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                            row2["S"] = dr["S"].ToString();
                            row2["T"] = DBNull.Value;
                            row2["U"] = res_dou;
                            row2["V"] = nombreArchivo;
                            dtSalida.Rows.Add(row2);

                            i++;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            lstMensaje.Items.Add("Error Fila: "+i+1+" -> "+ex.Message);
                        }

      OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
                    con.ConnectionString = "x";

                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        using (OracleBulkCopy bulkcopy = new OracleBulkCopy(con))
                        {

                            bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "tconsolida";
                            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dtSalida);

                        }
                        con.Close();
                        con.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        lstMensaje.Items.Add("Error al hacer bulk-> " + ex.Message);
                    }


                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                lstMensaje.Items.Add("Error General: " + ex.Message);
            }

     
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer uso del control `UpdateProgress`, que se utiliza junto al `UpdatePanel`

[UpdateProgress Control With UpdatePanel in AJAX](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/364074/updateprogress-control-with-updatepanel-in-ajax/)

La idea es que el `UpdatePanel` realice el submit de los datos al evento sin actualizar toda la pagina, por lo tanto permite al `UpdateProgress` mostrar un mensaje o `gif animado`

en el html del ejemplo veras que define

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="Up1" runat="Server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <span style="background-color:#66997A;"> <img src="img/images.jpg" alt="Please wait"  width="100px"/> Please wait ...</span>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

defines el template que se mostrar cuando se realiza el submit del `UpdatePanel`, por eso se asocian los controles `AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"`

Si tienes un `fileupload` hay un pequeño detalles que debrias seguir, lo explica el articulo

[Using FileUpload Control inside ASP.Net AJAX UpdatePanel Control](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-FileUpload-Control-inside-ASP.Net-AJAX-UpdatePanel-Control.aspx)

Comment: en mi pagina tengo un control fileupload, cuando ejecuto el updatepanel que comentaste, en el codebehind me genera un error "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto." como si no encontrara el control fileupload que puedo hacer?

Comment: edite la respuesta, agregue un articulo en donde explica como hacer funcionar el fileupload

Comment: ya edite la respuesta, agregando mi codigo

Comment: editaste mi respuesta, no la pregunta

Comment: ya esta el codigo en mi pregunta, me marca el error en el evento del boton, cuando lee: fuExcel.PostedFile.FileName.Length

Comment: coloque un tag  <Triggers> para que me leyera el contenido de mi fileUpload y ya me lo lee pero ahora no me muestra mi gif de cargando que esta en el tag <asp:UpdateProgress>, y cuando
quito el tag <Triggers> si me muestra el gif pero no lee el nombre del archivo del fileUpload, que puede ser amigo